# Couldn't match type `Int' with `[Char]'

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Начал изучать haskell по [книге](https://www.ohaskell.guide/let-n-where.html).

В процессе написал и попытался скомпилировать следующий код:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE MultiWayIf #-}


module Main where

calculateTime :: Int -> Int
calculateTime timeInS =
    let threshold  = 40
        correction = 120
    in
    if  | timeInS < threshold -> timeInS + correction
        | otherwise ->
            let delta = 8
            in
            timeInS + delta + correction

main :: IO()
main = putStrLn (calculateTime 50)
```

Но компиляция не завершилась, сообщив мне об ошибке:

```
app\Main.hs:18:18: error:
    * Couldn't match type `Int' with `[Char]'
      Expected type: String
        Actual type: Int
    * In the first argument of `putStrLn', namely `(calculateTime 50)'
      In the expression: putStrLn (calculateTime 50)
      In an equation for `main': main = putStrLn (calculateTime 50)
   |
18 | main = putStrLn (calculateTime 50)
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


--  While building package real-0.1.0.0 using:
      C:\sr\setup-exe-cache\x86_64-windows\Cabal-simple_Z6RU0evB_2.4.0.1_ghc-8.6.5.exe --builddir=.stack-work\dist\e626a42b build lib:real exe:real-exe --ghc-options " -fdiagnostics-color=always"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

---

Насколько я понял, `haskell` ожидал, что функция заменится строкой, но фактически это было число.

Я предполагал, что функция примет 1 аргумент (`timeInS`) типа `Int` (`50`) и отобразит его на тип `Int`, исходя из этого объявления:

```hs
calculateTime :: Int -> Int
```

После чего напечатает отобразившееся значение:

```
putStrLn (calculateTime 50)
```

В итоге, я ожидал, что программа напечатает мне `178`.

---

Где я допустил ошибку? И вообще, правильно ли я понял сообщение компилятора?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что `putStrLn` применяется только к значениям типа `[Char]` (он же `String`)

```hs
putStrLn :: String -> IO ()
```

Нужно либо использовать `show` для преобразования числа в строку

```hs
putStrLn (show (calculateTime 50))
```

Либо использовать `print`, который сделает ровно [то же самое](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/System.IO.html#print)

```hs
print (calculateTime 50)
```